# Procesamiento de resetear contraseña en laravel no funciona

Tags: laravel, app, contraseña

Estoy usando este código para realizar este proceso... Si se dan cuenta e mi plantilla php llamo al script para que se ejecute y resulta que no me muestra nada, en consola me muestra error con el script pero en un proyecto parecido funciona bien y aca en el mio pues no me permite resetear la contraseña, alguien puede guiarme al respecto sobre este proceso?
Este error me aparece en consola:
resetUsuario http://localhost/js/gestionar/usuario.js:256
onclick http://localhost/Dashboard:1

```js
function resetUsuario(id){ 
    let html_select = '<form method="post" id="frmResetDatos">';
        html_select += '<input type="hidden" name="identificador_reset" id="identificador_reset" value="'+data+'">';
        html_select += '<button type="button" onclick="resetDatosUsuario();" class="btn btn-success btn-sm boton-label">';
        html_select += '<i class="fas fa-trash icono-button"></i> Aceptar</button></form>';
        $('#ver_contenido_reset').html(html_select);
}
```

```html
@extends('layouts.reset')
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalResetUsuario" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="card panel-default">
        <div class="card-header titulo-popup-eliminar">
          <b>¡Resetear clave de usuario!</b>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <img src="{{asset('images/reset.png')}} " class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <p class="text-justify">¿Está seguro que desea resetear la clave a este usuario?
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm boton-label" data-dismiss="modal">
              <i class="fas fa-times icono-button"></i>Cancelar</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
              <div  id="ver_contenido_reset"></div>
            </div>
          </div>            

        </div>
      </div>        
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```